Drawing this diagram using Tikz

I want to draw this picture in duplicate side by side within a figure environment. Here the boundary is a circle. In the first subfigure environment, the five big subsets are to be shaded with a blue color. In the second subfigure environment, the five big subsets and all their intersection parts are to be shaded with red color. I tried using tikz but am not getting the exact form.
I tried this way:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
 \begin{figure}[]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[lightgray](0,0)circle(2cm);
\fill[blue!30,opacity=0.5] 
(0,0) .. controls (1,2) and (2,1) .. (3,0)
.. controls (1,-1) and (1,-2) .. (0,-3)
.. controls (-2,-1) and (-1,1) .. cycle;

\fill[blue!30,opacity=0.5]
(0.5,-1) .. controls (2,0.5) and (2.5,-2) .. (1,-2.5)
.. controls (-0.5,-1.5) and (-1,0.5) .. cycle;

\fill[blue!30,opacity=0.5]
(-1,-0.5) .. controls (0,2) and (2,-1) .. (1.5,-2)
.. controls (0,-1) and (-1.5,-1.5) .. cycle;

\fill[blue!30,opacity=0.5]
(-2,1) .. controls (-1,2) and (0,2.5) .. (1.5,1.5)
.. controls (1,-0.5) and (-1,-1.5) .. cycle;

\fill[blue!30,opacity=0.5]
(-1.5,0.5) .. controls (-2,1.5) and (-2,-1) .. (-1,-1.5)
.. controls (0,-1) and (0.5,0) .. cycle;
\begin{scope}
\clip(0,0)circle(2cm);
\fill[blue!80,opacity=0.5](0.5,-0.5)ellipse(0.8 and 0.4);
\fill[blue!80,opacity=0.5](-1.2,1.2)circle(0.5cm);
\fill[blue!80,opacity=0.5](1.2,1.2)circle(0.4cm);
\fill[blue!80,opacity=0.5](0,-1.5)ellipse(0.5 and 0.3);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\label{figure3.2.1a}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[lightgray](0,0)circle(2cm);
\fill[red!80,opacity=0.5](0,0)to[out=90,in=180](1,1.5)to[out=0,in=90](2,0)to[out=-90,in=0](1,-1.5)to[out=180,in=-90]cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\label{figure3.2.1b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{}
\label{figure3.2.1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}



Welcome! What have you tried so far?

Can you please try to write a more specific descriptive title for your question?
